# Passing arrays to derivative function vs tuples yields different scipy.integrate odeint results?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, odeint

I am looking at building a simple SEIR model using scipy.integrate. For now I am just running a single location, but I need to set it up to run on a vector of locations with transition probabilities between them. However when I pass variable to the odeint function as arrays instead of the standard tuple, it yields incorrect results!

This version works fine and gives correct output:

```
def deriv_correct(y, t, beta, gamma, alpha, mu, i):

    su = 1-mu

    S,E,I,R,D = y

    dSdt = -beta * i * S * I / (S+E+I+R)
    dEdt = beta * i * S * I / (S+E+I+R) - alpha*E
    dIdt = alpha*E - gamma * I
    dRdt = gamma * I * su
    dDdt = gamma * I * mu

    return dSdt,dEdt,dIdt,dRdt,dDdt

Forecast_days = 200
t = np.linspace(0, Forecast_days, Forecast_days)
y0 = 59000000, 500, 800, 0, 0
beta = 2.3/4
gamma  = 0.07
alpha = 0.25
mu = 0.02
i = 1

ret_correct = odeint(deriv_correct, y0, t, args=(beta, gamma, alpha, mu, i))
```

But this version, a duplication of above but with variables as arrays, returns incorrect results:

```
def deriv_wrong(y, t, beta, gamma, alpha, mu, i):

    su = np.ones_like(mu)-mu

    S = y[0]
    E = y[1]
    I = y[2]
    R = y[3]
    D = y[4]

    dSdt = -beta * i * S * I / (S+E+I+R)
    dEdt = beta * i * S * I / (S+E+I+R) - alpha*E
    dIdt = alpha*E - gamma * I
    dRdt = gamma * I * su
    dDdt = gamma * I * mu

    y_new = np.array([dSdt,dEdt,dIdt,dRdt,dDdt])
    y_new = np.squeeze(y_new)

    return y_new

Forecast_days = 200
t = np.linspace(0, Forecast_days, Forecast_days)
y0 = [59000000,709*2.3/4,709,0,0]
beta = np.array([2.3/4])
gamma  = np.array([1/14])
alpha = np.array([1/4])
mu = np.array([0.02])
i = np.array([1])

ret_wrong = odeint(deriv_wrong, y0, t, args=(beta, gamma, alpha, mu, i))
```

I'd appreciate some help on why this is happening. Both deriv_correct and deriv_wrong return the same results so it seems to be something with ODEINT

Comment: You are aware that you define gamma differently? Are you at least using python 3?

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. Even with the different gamma I get identical looking results in python 3. It seems to be an integer division problem, where in python 2 you get 1/4=0 and 1/14=0 in alpha and gamma.